# inDesign: Placed PDF hyperlinks won't work in exported Interactive PDF, Any fixes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, interactive, hyperlink

I have a document that made out of collage of a bunch of PDFs! These documents are contained with lits of Hyperlinked text and images, but when placed, and re-exported to Interactive PDF, they are not work (but do appear) in the final PDF.

Is there any option or way to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure InDesign is equipped to read and make active hyperlinks within *anything* which is embedded. You may have to reset the hyperlinks in Acrobat after export.